# Complex factory optimization

Tags: solidity, gas-estimate, factory, design-patterns

After two and a half years of developing smart contracts on a non-EVM blockchain (Tezos), I started working on a few solidity projects, and I'm trying to understand some things.

I built a factory contract, that deploys a few different smart contracts, saves their addresses and interacts with them.

My naive implementation, which on Tezos could potentially be problematic is importing the deployed smart contracts code into the main factory file, and doing everything directly from the factory, so a simplified example could look something like this:

**sub contract 1 `Foo.sol`:**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

contract Foo {
  uint uint1;
  uint uint2;

  constructor(uint _uint1, uint _uint2) {
    uint_1 = _uint_1;
    uint_2 = _uint_2;
  }
  function addOne() {
    uint_1 += 1;
    uint_2 += 1;
  }
}
```

**factory contract `Factory.sol`:**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

import "./Foo.sol";

contract Factory {
  mapping(uint => Foo) public foos;
  uint next_foo_id;

  function addFoo(uint _uint_1, uint _uint_2) public {
    Foo foo = new Foo(_uint_1, _uint_2);
    foos[next_foo_id] = foo;
    next_foo_id += 1;
  }
  function addOneInFoo(uint _foo_id) public {
    Foo foo = foos[_foo_id];
    foo.addOne();
  }
}
```

Ok, so this works just fine, as long as there are not many different types of contracts deployed, and the deployed contracts are not very large in size. The problem starts when those conditions are not met, and there are many fairly large contracts handled by the factory. Then I start getting some complaints from the hardhat tests, saying that the code is too large, and gas consumption estimation can not be done and this could potentially lead to failing deployments on real chains (mainnet or testnet). Indeed, when I try to deploy such a large factory on Goerli, the deployment fails (actually, when I deploy from Remix it works, but not from hardhat).

Now, I was half expecting this to happen (although I was hoping not), because I know from experience on Tezos that the factory needs to include all the bytecode (`Michelson` opcode on Tezos) in its own code, which could inflate the code to a very large size.

So my next implementation is using `launcher` proxy contracts, and interacting with those instead:

***launcher contract `FooLauncher.sol`:***

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;
import "./Foo.sol";

contract Factory {
  function addFooAddress(uint _foo_id, Foo _foo_address) {}
}

contract FooLauncher {
  Factory factory_address;

  constructor(address _factory_address) {
    factory_address = Factory(_factory_address);
  }
  function launchFoo(uint _foo_id, uint _uint_1, uint _uint_2) public {
    Foo foo = new Foo(_uint_1, _uint_2);
    factory_address.addFooAddress(_foo_id, foo);
  }
}
```

And `Factory.sol` would now look something like this:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

contract FooLauncher {
  function launchFoo(uint _foo_id, uint _uint_1, uint _uint_2) public {}
}
contract Foo {
  function addOne() public {}
}

contract Factory {
  mapping(uint => Foo) public foos;
  uint next_foo_id;
  FooLauncher foo_launcher;

  function addFoo(uint _uint_1, uint _uint_2) public {
    foo_launcher.launchFoo(next_foo_id, _uint_1, _uint_2);
    next_foo_id += 1;

  }

  function addFooAddress(uint _foo_id, Foo _foo_address) {
    foos[_foo_id] = _foo_address;
  }

  function addOneInFoo(uint _foo_id) public {
    Foo foo = foos[_foo_id];
    foo.addOne();
  }
}
```

So this solution works, no more code size issues, but now, in my real implementation, in which I have several different contracts with many data structures and many cross-contract interactions, the code just becomes ugly, difficult to navigate and difficult to test. Each contract file needs to define a bunch of other pseudo-contracts with the structures and functions used by it.

Is there a neater way to do this? Am I missing some solidity tricks that can be used here?
Thanks!

Comment: I'd uses some sort of proxy.